# Rackspace - How to export a Block Storage Volume?

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace, vhd, cloudfiles, rackspace-cloudfiles

I'm having problems doing this, I don't know if it is possible with any tool from this cloud, or with any third party tool, and that is why my question, since I have been searching without success.

The thing is that I have a Block Storage Volume that I need to export (it is not a root volume), this is attached to a Cloud server running debian 7, now, I managed to export the root volume as .vhd, but not this second volume. Does any of you know a way to do it? Thanks in advance!.

I tried creating an image of the cloud server with both volumes, the root and the associated cloud block storage, both mounted on the file system, I exported that image to a .vhd format, but it only exported the root volume and not the second volume.

I was hoping that both volumes would be contained in the image.